# Select Multiple rows into one row in Oracle

Tags: oracle, select, oracle11g

I have a table that stores student results for different exams and different exam types say main exam, continuous assessment, course work etc, I need to query the table such that I get only one row for one particular exam unit with the percentage averaged depending on the number of exams the students sat for. Here is my attempted query:

```
select stu_reg_no, unit_code, 
       exam_unit, exam_semester, 
       student_year,  
       sum(per_centage_score)/count(per_centage_score) percentage
 from student_results_master
group by unit_code, exam_unit, 
         per_centage_score, stu_reg_no,  
         exam_semester, student_year;
```

Here is my resultset:

[image]

I have two rows for the same exam unit since one is main exam and the other course work I need my output like this:

```
E35/1000/2013   TFT001  COMPLEX ANALYSIS   1  1  71.04
E35/1000/2013   TFT002  LINEAR ALGEBRA     1  1  56.25
```

The percentage for that particular unit is added and divided by the number of exams for that particular unit.
How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oracle provides a built-in function for calculating average value for an expression over a set of rows - [AVG()](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions018.htm). To get the desired output you need to do the following two things:

1. Replace `sum(per_centage_score)/count(per_centage_score)` with `avg(per_centage_score)`
2. Remove `per_centage_score` column from the `group by` clause.

To that end, your query might look like this:

```
select stu_reg_no
     , unit_code
     , exam_unit
     , exam_semester
     , student_year
     , avg(percentage) percentage
 from student_results_master
group by unit_code
       , exam_unit
       , stu_reg_no
       , exam_semester
       , student_year;
```

Result:

```
STU_REG_NO    UNIT_CODE EXAM_UNIT        EXAM_SEMESTER STUDENT_YEAR PERCENTAGE
------------- --------- ---------------- ------------- ------------ ----------
E35/1000/2013 TFT001    COMPLEX ANALYSIS             1            1      71.04 
E35/1000/2013 TFT002    LINEAR ALGEBRA               1            1      56.25
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
select stu_reg_no, unit_code, exam_unit, exam_semester, student_year,  
(select sum(per_centage_score) from student_results_master t2 where t2.exam_unit = t1.exam_unit)
/(select count(per_centage_score) from student_results_master t2 where t2.exam_unit = t1.exam_unit)
from student_results_master t1
group by unit_code, exam_unit, stu_reg_no,  exam_semester, student_year;
```

Comment: Your rows are still four instead of two :P